# How to set attributes inside Android layout that is included in another layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, include

I have a composite widget that consists of an ImageView and TextView object wrapped up inside a LinearLayout. Since this is used several times inside one of my activities I made it a separate layout and include it multiple times inside the main layout. I understand you can override the view id for the included layout from the  tag in the main layout. My question is, is it possible to set things like the image source and textview string from the main layout in XML? Sure, I could do this programmatically but I was wondering if it was possible purely in XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html):

> You can include any other layout
>   attributes in the <include> that are
>   supported by the root element in the
>   included layout and they will override
>   those defined in the root element.

It sounds like you can only override the layout_* attributes. (One might be tempted take a look at the source code to see if something else is secretly supported, but that would be a no-no in terms of forward compatibility.)

Comment: The docs say this is a good way of reusing a composite widget but its only useful if the widget stays exactly the same. If you want to reuse the widget with say, different text in it, you can't use this technique at all.

Comment: @Eno - I agree. It would be very nice if one could define parameterized XML fragments that could be reused.