# <include> tag override attribute

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

If I have one layout file => `res/layout/item.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>            
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="John"
        />

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip" 
        android:text="29" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I have another layout file whose content includes several of above item=> `res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>            
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"        
    >

    <!--How can I override "name" and "age" attribute in the included item layout-->        

    <include android:id="@+id/student" layout="@layout/tem" />

    <include android:id="@+id/teacher" layout="@layout/item" />

    <include android:id="@+id/other" layout="@layout/item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you see above, I use `<include>` tag to include the same layout. But, how can I override the "`name`" and "`age`" text value in the included **item.xml** from **main.xml** for each included item??

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use the `include` tag only if you plan to reuse the exact `item` layout in other activities of the same app.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631614/does-android-xml-layouts-include-tag-really-work and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801710/how-to-set-attributes-inside-android-layout-that-is-included-in-another-layout namely you can only override layout_* attributes

Comment: Do you mean, even all the layout are the same for the "student", "teacher" and "other" items, I still can not use <include>? BUT is there any way to avoid repeatedly create the same layout code with only the text value different??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I hope this will work.

View v=(View)findviewbyid(R.id.student);

Textview name=(TextView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.name);

Textview age=(TextView)v.findviewbyid(R.id.age);
```

Comment: This seems like it would do the trick. Why is it downvoted?
 - Although, this won't work for preference layouts because they automatically store pref data with the given key (it will not differentiate between different instances of the include).

Answer (score -1):

change your item.xml as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>            
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"

>

    <TextView
        android:tag="item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="John"
        />

    <TextView  
        android:tag="item_age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip" 
        android:text="29" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then:

```
//find the container which hold student: 
     ViewGroup containerStudent = findViewById(R.id.student);
   //find the child:
     TextView student_name =(TextView)containerStudent.findViewWithTag("item_name");
```